# How to customize drop down menu for spinner?

Tags: android

I need to customize the yellow drop down menu in my custom spinner it needs to be moved to the right side and text need to be aligned left side in their row.

Example below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a spinner, you can assign two different templates to the display.  One is for the selection and one is for the dropdown.

It's set in the data adapter for the spinner.  Here is actual code we use:

```
    _spinDestination = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinDestination);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner
            , OrderDestRerouteDao.getList(_OrderDAO.getID(), _OrderDAO.getDestinationId()));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    _spinDestination.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The dropdownviewresource is what you want to pay attention to here.  It controls what the dropdown looks like.

Now inside your layout for the page, add these tags to your spinner:

```
android:dropDownHorizontalOffset = "?" 
android:dropDownVerticalOffset = "?"
```

where ? = an offset number (example: 50dp)

The layout change will offset your dropdown.  To get any other styling of it (such as width) you'll require the custom template for it.

[image: moved_the_dropdown]

As per request, here's the complete xml for my spinner.

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_shape"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCaption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/upper_corner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/heading_order_reroute_page_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/heading_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/label_current_destination"
                android:textSize="@dimen/caption_text_size"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:contentDescription="@drawable/star"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCurrentDestination"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/caption_text_size"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/label_new_destination"
                android:textSize="@dimen/caption_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:contentDescription="@drawable/star"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinDestination"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:dropDownHorizontalOffset = "?"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset = "?" 
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/label_reroute_notes"
                android:textSize="@dimen/caption_text_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:contentDescription="@drawable/star"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRerouteNotes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReroute"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_forward"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_complete_order_reroute_caption"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_reject"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_cancel_caption"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. Why you set it to THIS instead of adapter?

Comment: could you give example how to implement it in custom spinner? because in custom it looks like not work

Comment: this is the class that sample was in.  Actually give me a sec to paste different code.  I think that code is wrong in our project.

Comment: Ok now try that code.  I know this one works.  I wrote the page it's on and it uses two different templates.  The main one has a fake arrow on it to make it look like a combobox.

Comment: Thank you. But I have found solution by myself and it is very different. I will post it later

Comment: the question is still how to make this item align to right side of the top title

Comment: and i told you how.  You need to make a xml template for it, then use it with setDropDownViewResource

Comment: the thing was in inflation in adapter. setPopupBackgroundDrawable thats the problem which is not working and I cant move dropdownmenu to right side

Comment: did you try creating the layout for it?  It accepts all tags in the layout including width.

Comment: you can also add these tags to your main view's layout to offset horizontally and vertically (from inside the spinner's xlm) android:dropDownHorizontalOffset and android:dropDownVerticalOffset.  
that will give you your offset.  The width will be in the template.

Comment: Does horizontal works for you? Did you try it? Because mine is not moving

Comment: I did try it.  There are some caveats i probably should have mentioned. You can't move it past the edge of the layout.  If you don't shrink it first and you're filling the layout, you won't see it move.  I posted a screenshot of me moving it to "-200dp" (quotes are required)

Comment: android:dropDownHorizontalOffset suppose to be in spinner tag right? i tried -200dp -10dp 10dp 100dp and its not moving at all. Could you please post the xml of your layout with spinner?

Comment: yes.  did you put it in quotes though?  It has to be in quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. But it really not working. I thing it might be problems in parent views. So thats why I asked to public your layout to see your structure

Comment: give me a minute.  I'll post the entire layout.  No problem.  I'm happy to help.  I have fought these spinners myself in the past.

Comment: i've posted the layout.  I would get the resizing of the control working first though.  If it's not smaller it may not move.

Comment: layout xml of support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item ?

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar could you ask that better?  I don't know what you're asking.